# Why do power supplies fail?

Tags: power-supply, lifetime, component-failure

I want to buy this power supply [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HHKX0BG)

It says that it can last from 5-8 years. It can last 5-8 years by using it constantly? Also why do they fail? What component inside them causes them to fail? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Where does it say it can last 5-8 years?

Comment: @EugeneSh. oops. It doesn't say that in the description. It says it next to the "Add to list" button

Comment: OK, I see it "long lifetime upto 5-8 years". So it is how long it is typically working with a typical usage

Comment: @EugeneSh. but what causes it to fail? What components usually break down?

Comment: Components wearing? Corrosion? Bad usage? Dust accumulation affecting cooling? Many factors.

Comment: Lifetime (if properly calculated) is an MTBF (mean time between failures) figure based on an overall calculation of failure rates of all components. | A and perhaps THE major failure mode is electrolytic capacitor degradation. ECap lifetimes about double per 10 degrees drop in their mean operating temperature - so keeping a supply cool and/or blowing more cool air over the Ecaps and/or lightly loading it on average are all probably useful factors. If there are other heavily loaded  components they too will usually benefit from additional cooling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mention under what conditions (ambient temperature, moisture, load, dust amount, etc) it can last for the given 5 to 8 years. Some equipment are rated in hours total, or years of normal office use when used for 8 hours per day for 5 days a week. Usually power supplies have electrolytic capacitors that just have a limited hours of use, but any component can fail under stress. If you want specifications that define how long a power supply lasts under some given conditions, perhaps search for a power supply that defines them.

Comment: if i replace bad capacitors and dust it regulary it can last longer?

Comment: Maybe, who knows. If it breaks, it might be fixable, or it might not be. At that price, you can ask yourself if is it really worth fixing and do you even get a service manual.

Comment: There are similar power supplies on Ebay that cost considerably less.

Comment: @Barry, an old saying comes to mind ... `you get what you pay for`